# Self-hosted WCF service EndpointNotFoundException while using LAN

Tags: c#, wcf, service, wcf-endpoint

I've written 2 simple console applications one that is hosting a wcf service and second that is wcf service client.

If I run both applications on one machine (host and client) it works ok, but if I try to move client or host to different machine I get `EndpintNotFountException` when trying to connect to the host.

This is my code of the service :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    using System.ServiceModel;

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISimpleService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Register(string name);
    }
}
```

And implementing class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    public class SimpleService : ISimpleService
    {
        public void Register(string name)
        {
            DataBase.Save(name);
        }
    }
}
```

As you see it's very simple service :)

This is the code of host program :

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var service = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleService));
        service.Open();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            foreach (var s in DataBase.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It opens service and when enter pressed it will print the content of the data base. I know that it does not have `Close()` and other stuff but it is only for showing my problem.

Here is the `app.config` file :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name ="myBinding">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client />
    <services>
      <service name="ConsoleApplication7.SimpleService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBinding" contract="ConsoleApplication7.ISimpleService"/>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleApplication7.ISimpleService"/>
        <endpoint address ="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9101"/>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9102"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client code:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Click to open");
        Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            var service = new ServiceReference1.SimpleServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.11:9102/"));
            service.Open();
            service.Register("itsMe");
        }
        catch (Exception  e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Client `app.config` is created by visual studio by `AddServiceReference` option.

I host `app.config` file I tried both `http://localhost:9102` and `http://192.168.1.11:9102` as base addresses.

When open host and client applications on one machine it works fine. When I move one of those apps to other machine it returns `System.EndpointNotFoundException` when doing `client.Open()`.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong ? I've tried with `net.tcp` binding and its the same result.

Windows firewall is disabled on both machines

Comment: What about system firewall? Do you unblock the 9102 for incoming requests?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention changing the service address when you move the client or service to a different machine.  The address you're using - `localhost:xxxx` will only be recognized on the machine the program is on, so for example if you're service is on Machine1 and you move the client to Machine2, the client will not be able to see the service as it will expect it to be on Machine2.  You're probably running into a similar problem with the IP address, though that looks more like a router address.

I would suggest updating the service's config file to use the machine name (for example, `http://machine1:9102`), and using that address to access the service from the client.  For example:

```
var service = new ServiceReference1.SimpleServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://machine1:9102/"));
```

Comment: I mentioned that I've tried setting baseAddress in host app.config as `http://localhost:9102` and as `http://192.168.1.11:9102` (which is an ip address of host machine).
I've not tried with machine name but I don't see how it might work if with ip address it does not work ?